# How to treat chest pain due to treadmill overwork?

Tags: running, injury, injury-prevention

The doctors cannot find anything wrong with my heart, but it is in the region of the heart that I feel a discomfort close to dumb pain - maybe in front of heart, close to chest bones. It started after I increased to 40 minutes the time I used to run on the treadmill - before that I ran not more than 30 mins. Then, I took a week off, during which I did not run but only walked, and the chest pain disappeared. I resumed my workouts gradually increasing the time of running, but the pain appeared again, now after 20 minutes of running. I gave up running on treadmill for a whole month and the pain disappeared completely, but when I resumed and gradually increased the running time, the pain re-appeared after 10 minutes.  It is long since this became a permanent condition which prevents me from excercising. Can anybody recommend something to treat this?

Comment: You mention "doctors"; have you consulted with a cardiologist or two?

Comment: Yes, I consulted a cardiologist recently and another one earlier,  and I went through various blood analyses, tests, but there is nothing with my heart.

Comment: I'd say keep monitoring your heart regularly. And follow the advice of the doctors regarding workout. Also ensure your lungs are in good condition including diaphragm. Sometimes pain in those reasons can be mistaken with that of heart.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Chest Pain When Running: Causes and Remedies](http://www.md-health.com/Chest-Pain-When-Running.html)